# C#: How to add subitems in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list, view

Creating an item(Under the key) is easy,but how to add subitems(Value)?

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Key");
listView1.Columns.Add("Value");
listView1.Items.Add("sdasdasdasd");
//How to add "asdasdasd" under value?
```

Comment: try this. listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" }));

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like this:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.SubItems.Add("SubItem");
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Answer (score 30):

You whack the subitems into an array and add the array as a list item.

The order in which you add values to the array dictates the column they appear under so think of your sub item headings as [0],[1],[2] etc.

Here's a code sample:

```
//In this example an array of three items is added to a three column listview
string[] saLvwItem = new string[3];

foreach (string wholeitem in listofitems)
{
     saLvwItem[0] = "Status Message";
     saLvwItem[1] = wholeitem;
     saLvwItem[2] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss");

     ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(saLvwItem);

     lvwMyListView.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: Er... I've used this technique about four times in the last fortnight. Why the downvotes?

Comment: +1 for offering a perfectly valid alternative to the other answers. Why you received a downvote I do not know.

Comment: An easier alternative is to do it as such: `listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{"Col1", "SubItem2", "SubItem3", "And so on"}));`

Answer (score 15):

Suppose you have a List Collection containing many items to show in a ListView, take the following example that iterates through the List Collection:

```
foreach (Inspection inspection in anInspector.getInspections())
  {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text=anInspector.getInspectorName().ToString();
    item.SubItems.Add(inspection.getInspectionDate().ToShortDateString());
    item.SubItems.Add(inspection.getHouse().getAddress().ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(inspection.getHouse().getValue().ToString("C"));
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
  }
```

That code produces the following output in the ListView (of course depending how many items you have in the List Collection):

Basically the first column is a listviewitem containing many subitems (other columns). It may seem strange but listview is very flexible, you could even build a windows-like file explorer with it!

Comment: This logic should be under the `Inspection` class since it has to know all the internals...

Answer (score 3):

I've refined this using an extension method on the ListViewItemsCollection. In my opinion it makes the calling code more concise and also promotes more general reuse.

```
internal static class ListViewItemCollectionExtender
{
    internal static void AddWithTextAndSubItems(
                                   this ListView.ListViewItemCollection col, 
                                   string text, params string[] subItems)
    {
        var item = new ListViewItem(text);
        foreach (var subItem in subItems)
        {
            item.SubItems.Add(subItem);
        }
        col.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Calling the AddWithTextAndSubItems looks like this:

```
// can have many sub items as it's string array
myListViewControl.Items.AddWithTextAndSubItems("Text", "Sub Item 1", "Sub Item 2");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very nice, but what is passed as the ListView.ListViewItemCollection when calling this extension method?

Comment: @ClayShannon: as it's an extension method it "extends" the behaviour of the .NET FX ListView.ListViewItemCollection. The compiler turns the extension method style into a call to the static method. So   `myListViewControl.Items.AddWithTextAndSubItems("Text", "Sub Item 1", "Sub Item 2");` becomes  `ListViewItemCollectionExtender.AddWithTextAndSubItems(myListViewControl.Items, "Text", "Sub Item 1", "Sub Item 2");`   Compiler magic!!

Answer (score 3):

I think the quickest/neatest way to do this:

For each class have `string[] obj.ToListViewItem()` method and then do this:

```
foreach(var item in personList)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item.ToListViewItem()));
}
```

Here is an example definition

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public uint ID { get; set; }

    public string[] ToListViewItem()
    {
        return new string[] {
            ID.ToString("000000"),
            Name,
            Address,
            DOB.ToShortDateString()
        };
    }
}
```

As an added bonus you can have a `static` method that returns `ColumnHeader[]` list for setting up the listview columns with

```
listView1.Columns.AddRange(Person.ListViewHeaders());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = "fdfdfd";
item.SubItems.Add ("melp");
listView.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: What is ListItem,the compiler doesn't recognise it.

Comment: I'm sure he meant ListViewItem.

Comment: Listviewitem offcourse, sorry for the typo, but with a little bit of effort I'm sure you should've found out yourself that it is ListViewItem instead of ListItem.  Check out the MSDN and overloaded Add methods of the Items property of the listview ...

Answer (score 2):

Create a listview item

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("sdasdasdasd", 0)
item1.SubItems.Add("asdasdasd")
```

Answer (score 2):

add:

```
.SubItems.Add("asdasdasd");
```

to the last line of your code so it will look like this in the end.

```
listView1.Items.Add("sdasdasdasd").SubItems.Add("asdasdasd");
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Column1Text")
   { Tag = optionalRefToSourceObject };

item.SubItems.Add("Column2Text");
item.SubItems.Add("Column3Text");
myListView.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Great !! It has helped me a lot. I used to do the same using VB6 but now it is completely different.
we should add this

```
listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
listView1.GridLines = true; 
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```