# Windows Forms Listbox Multible Lists in same Box

Tags: winforms

I'm working on a project where I'm getting a list of contacts from a webservice. These contacts have names and emails and each of thoose I save in a list of strings. Now I want my listbox to take in the names and the emails and write them in 2 columns. Then I want to be able to select one set in the listbox and get the email or name in that set. My problem is I cant find a method for doing the multicolumn thing. The only thing I've found is the Listbox.MultiColumn attribute but it seems to take 1 list and just divide it into more columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ListBoxes don't support multiple columns (MultiColumn just spreads the existing items across columns, as you have seen)

An alternative would be to use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) set in Details mode instead, and add each column as a SubItem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729090/c-how-to-add-subitems-in-listview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx)
You can add rows like this:

```
string[] row1 = new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "..." };
string[] row2 = new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "..." };
// And so on
object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2 };

foreach (string[] row in rows)
{
    yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
}
```