# Process.Start issue Launching my game

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

Currently I'm trying to program a launcher for my game. My issue is, if you launch my game this way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\game.bat");
```

I get an unhandled exception or could not find error.

But if I do it this way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"game.bat");
```

It works. Where is the issue ?

Comment: Post your exact exception (not a paraphrase)

Comment: Btw, the relative path is a better solution anyway.. that is if you set the working directory correctly.

Comment: is Game.bat in your \bin folder?

Comment: Either Path not Correct for the First sample, Is the game.bat file in bin/Debug folder for Second sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the batch file resides in the same directory as your program launcher. Determine its location automatically:

```
string executableDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
Process.Start(Path.Combine(executableDir, "game.bat"));
```

Where

- `Application.ExecutablePath` is the path of your executable, i.e.
  `F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\justshoot.exe`.
- `Path.GetDirectoryName(...)` gets the directory part of it, i.e.
  `F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot`.
- `Path.Combine(executableDir, "game.bat")` combines the directory with `game.bat`, i.e. `F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\game.bat`

---

Keep also in mind that when started from Visual Studio the executable path is `"...\bin\Debug"` or `"...\bin\Release"`. Therefore you might want to remove these parts from the path if your batch file resides in the project directory.

```
const string DebugDir = @"\bin\Debug";
const string ReleaseDir = @"\bin\Release";

string executableDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
if (executableDir.EndsWith(DebugDir)) {
    executableDir =
        executableDir.Substring(0, executableDir.Length - DebugDir.Length);
} else if (executableDir.EndsWith(ReleaseDir)) {
    executableDir =
        executableDir.Substring(0, executableDir.Length - ReleaseDir.Length);
}
Process.Start(Path.Combine(executableDir, "game.bat"));
```

---

**UPDATE**

It is not a good idea the hard code the directories. Place the paths of the games to be launched in a text file in the same directory as your game launcher (e.g. "launch.txt"). Each line would contain a game that can be launched with the name of the game plus its path. Like this:

```
Freak Mind Games = F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\game.bat
Minecraft = C:\Programs\Minecraft\minecraft.exe
```

Define a directory as variable in your form:

```
private Dictionary<string,string> _games;
```

Now get a list of these games like this:

```
string executableDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string launchFile = Path.Combine(executableDir, "launch.txt"));

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(launchFile);

// Fill the dictionary with the game name as key and the path as value.
_games = lines
    .Where(l => l.Contains("="))
    .Select(l => l.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
```

Then display the game names in a `ListBox`:

```
listBox1.AddRange(
     _games.Keys
        .OrderBy(k => k)
        .ToArray()
);
```

Finally launch the selected game with

```
string gamePath = _games[listBox1.SelectedItem];
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(gamePath);
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(gamePath);
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: OK This is my code:
namespace GameLauncher
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string executableDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            Process.Start(Path.Combine(executableDir, @"F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\game.bat"));
        }
    }
}
and this are the two errors I've got:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42689244/error1.JPG
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42689244/error2.JPG

Comment: The variable `executableDir` contains the directory already. Therefore drop the directory part of your path! `Path.Combine(executableDir, "game.bat")`. Probably `executableDir` contains: `"F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot"`.

Comment: sorry. I don't understand. Where do I have to place my path F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\ ?

Comment: Nowhere! `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` gives you the directory of `justshoot.exe`.

Comment: But I don't want to place it in the folder :P
Now, when I place it in the folder of Just Shoot it runs but I don't wanna do this :P

Comment: Where do you want to place "game.bat" in relation to your game launcher (I assume its "justshoot.exe") then?

Comment: This should be not a launcher for only this game ! this should become a launcher for multiple games

Comment: var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\JustShootLauncher.exe");
            processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"F:\Freak Mind Games\Projects 2013\JustShoot\JustShootLauncher.exe");
            Process.Start(processStartInfo);

Comment: I added an update explaining a possible solution where the launchable games are configured in a text file. (Note: I have not tested the code.)

Comment: Awww. Where do I have to put this in ? Form_load ?
I've got an issue with .AddRange :(

Comment: Ok fixed the other stuff.
This is my only issue right now :P
_games[listBox1.SelectedItem];

Can't convert object in string

Comment: Can we replace the listBox with a listView ? Then I can add name, publisher and a background to it :)

Comment: Of course you can. I'm not very used to ListViews, they are bit more complicated to handle. You have to define the headers and to add sub-items. See [C#: How to add subitems in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/729090/880990)