# Source of listview - Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listview

I have List of objects of class Book:

```
 public static List<Book> ListBooks = new List<Book>() {
            new Book(1, "Title", "Author", 2004)            };
```

Now, I want to insert this list to ListView in Window Form. In WPF it's easy, but in Windows Forms "DataSource" does not work.

I added some columns, but how can I bind this list to listview?

Comment: You may consider using readonly `DataGridView` instead.

Comment: I must use ListView. This is the requirement for the task.

Comment: Then you have to populate it manually. WinForms `ListView` (and `TreeView`) controls do not support data binding :(

Comment: What do you think about using the loop, which will add this data to ListView in some way?

Comment: Question with examples on how to fill a ListView with subitems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729090/c-how-to-add-subitems-in-listview and of course MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I found solution, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found solution:

```
foreach (Book b in Program.ListBooks)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                lvi.Text = b.IdBook.ToString();
                lvi.SubItems.Add(b.Author);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(b.Title);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(b.Year.ToString());
                listViewBooks.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```