# Cannot convert from 'int' to System.Windows.Form.ListViewItem.ListViewSubitem

Tags: c#, listview

I been having a problem in may col - 1 it said that
*Cannot convert from 'int' to System.Windows.Form.ListViewItem.ListViewSubitem*

i tried this code but didn't work  `ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem();`

this is my code:

```
Item.SubItems.Add(col - 1).Text = "IN-GATE USER";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.SubItems.Add("IN-GATE USER");
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

You have more information on this answer: [C#: How to add subitems in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729090/c-how-to-add-subitems-in-listview)

Comment: it works dude
can i ask one more?
can you explain why did he do this??
Item.SubItems.Add(col - 1).Text = rsUser.GetData(Convert.ToInt16(i)).ToString();

and it also the same error in col also